# Highlight both row and cell on grid item select

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there a standard way to highlight active row in a grid like in attached screen?

I mean having a grid, with [cellmodel](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.selection.CellModel) selection type, when clicking on an item in the grid, it highlights the cell. I would like to highlight the active row at the same time.

It is very useful when gird contain a lots of data to be analysed,
when selecting cell, and entire row (maybe collumn?) needs to be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: I thought row is highlighted when you select a cell? Do you mean you want the cell to be highlighted in different color?

Comment: when the config **"selType : 'rowmodel'"**, yeah!! the row is highlighted when it's selected.. but when **"selType : 'cellmodel'"**, when you select, the cell is highlighted.. so I'd like to have **"selType : 'cellmodel'"**, to highlight the cell and row at the same time, maybe with different colors..

Comment: afaik it can't be done without extending `RowModel` and build up a customized Row Selection Model to achieve this type of interaction.

Comment: ok.. thanks! waiting for extjs 5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys. We did it :) Here is the one possible solution :

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CellModel', {
    listeners: {
        select: function (cellModel, record, rowIndex) {
            var myGrid = this.items.get('gridItemId');
            myGrid.getView().addRowCls(rowIndex, 'row-style');
        },
        deselect: function (cellModel, record, rowIndex) {
            var myGrid = this.items.get('gridItemId');
            myGrid.getView().removeRowCls(rowIndex, 'row-style');
        },
        scope: this
    }
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use addRowCls method of grid which Adds a CSS Class to a specific row.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.View-method-addRowCls

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are using the CellSelectionModel, you could easily apply styles/classes to the row the selected cell is in. If you take a look at the events for CellSelectionModel, you'll see the `cellselect` actually returns the rowIndex.

> **cellselect** : ( SelectionModel *this*, Number **rowIndex**, Number colIndex )

So, what you could so is something like the following:

```
// we'll say you have your Grid stored in a variable, grid
CellSelectionModel ...({
    listeners: {
        'cellselect': function(selModel, rowIndex) {
            var cellRow = grid.getView().getRow(rowIndex);
            Ext.fly(cellRow).addClass('selectedRow')
            // do any other logic with the actual DOM element here
    }
})
```